# Flex: Setting the resgistration point on a display object

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

What is the best way to change/set a registration point on a Flex 3 display object? I know this isn't really built in to easily change, but does anyone have any suggestions on how I could extend UIComponent to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the Flash Player API doesn't expose the registration point of `DisplayObjects` (and the Flash IDE makes them a pain to modify once an object is created). The best solution, as David pointed out, is to add your component as a child of another component (`UIComponent` would be fine). So, for example, if I had a `Button` and I wanted its registration point at its center, I'd add it as a child of a `UIComponent` (not `Canvas`) and offset the child by setting its position to `(-button.width/2, -button.height/2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your DisplayObject inside a sprite and set the DisplayObject's x & y positions to the negitive of your target registration point. Apply all transforms to the Sprite container.

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside a `Canvas` container, with its `clipContent` attribute set to false.  Within the canvas, you can put your object wherever you like.

Comment: Canvas adds some pretty big overhead if you'll be doing this for many display objects. Members of Adobe's Flex team recommend keeping the number of containers in a Flex application to a minimum.